# Problems with Injecting Implementations into abstract classes with python-inject 5.1.0

Tags: python, python-inject

I'm trying to use python-inject 5.1.0 and I'm unable to inject a class implemented into an abstract class.

```
class JobGateway(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_by_id(self, id: str):
        pass
    
class JobGatewayImpl(JobGateway):
    @inject.autoparams()
    def __init__(self, db: Database):
        self.collection = db["jobs"]

    def get_by_id(self, id: str):
        data = self.collection.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(id)})

        if data is None:
            return None

        return data

class MessageProcessor:
    @inject.autoparams()
    def __init__(
        self,
        job_gateway: JobGateway
    ) -> None:
        self.job_gateway = job_gateway

    def run(self, id):
        job = self.job_gateway.get_by_id(id)
```

My optional configuration:

```
binder.bind_to_constructor(JobGateway, lambda: inject.instance(JobGatewayImpl))
```

When I get a MessageProcessor instance, job_gateway does not get the JobGatewayImpl implementation.

```
processor: MessageProcessor = inject.instance(MessageProcessor)
```

But, when I try to get the instance directly, JobGatewayImpl is obtained successfully.

```
j2: JobGateway = inject.instance(JobGateway)
```

Why is the JobGatewayImpl implementation not injected into the processor?

I would like that when running the line

```
processor: MessageProcessor = inject.instance(MessageProcessor)
```

dependency JobGateway obtains the instance of JobGatewayImpl